# Symfony 4 routing issue -- debug:router shows route, route:match says 'none of the routes match the path X'

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony4

I'm working with Symfony 4, PHP 7.2, doing an update from Symfony 3 and PHP 7.1

```
One of the routines (call it XXYY) now fails to route.   This occurs both on Windows using symfony server, and on apache on a Linux box.  On other routines, routing works.

From Windows:    >  php bin/console debug:router | findstr "XXYY"                yields
```

XXYY    GET|POST   https         ANY    /{_locale}/XXYY

```
From Windows:     > php bin/console route:match XXYY                             yields
```

[ERROR] None of the routes match the path "XXYY"

```
From Linux:  # php bin/console debug:router | grep XXYY             yields
```

XXYY  GET|POST   https         ANY    /{_locale}/XXYY

From Linux:  # php bin/console route:match XXYY                     yields
 [ERROR] None of the routes match the path "XXYY".

```
  Any help in understanding how to debug routing, when symfony's two tools disagree as to the status, greatly appreciated.
                                Best....Doug
```

Comment: `route:match` matches a **path** (i.e. everything after the domain and before query/fragment) and since XXYY is not equal to /{_locale}/XXYY (since slashes and locale is missing) no routes are found. have you tried `route:match /en/XXYY` (or whatever your locale is)? thus, route:match simulates what the router does, when the webserver gives it a request with that path.

Comment: @Jakumi -- many thanks for helping.    I just tried php bin/console route:match /en/XXYY, and still get  [ERROR] None of the routes match the path "/en/XXYY".  I am thinking it has something to do with order in which 
        /config/packages/routing.yaml
        /config/prod/routing.yaml
        /config/packages/securityyaml
 are processed.   I have an access_control: entry in the security.yaml file that assigns a role to the path where XXYY lives.    I'm thinking somehow it isn't passing that, but don't know how to test where routing fails.   That other routines work means most code OK.

Comment: When I use the -verbose option for route:match, I get the following:
Route "XXYY" almost matches but scheme "http" does not match any of the required schemes (https)             All of my routines use annotations to force the use of https:/

Comment: ensuring https is usually not symfony's job (usually the webserver does this) and usually defaults should be left as is because there's too much to do wrong. especially for development, demanding https by default is overkill. symfony serve / console server:run is not for production scenarios btw. So, your solution is to not demand https and be done with it.